# MSMQ compatibilty

Tags: xml, msmq, compatibility

I was wondering if a VB6 app (Using MSMQ version 1) sending a message which contains an XML (Microsoft version 2.0) to a private queue can be read on the receiving end with C# application (using MSMQ version 5.0 / XML from .NET 4.0)

thx

Answer (score 1):

The version of MSMQ doesn't matter here as all versions are compatible. There are [minor gotchas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/06/29/the-message-format-has-changed-in-msmq-4-0-so-re-test-all-your-applications.aspx), though. Also, you may find some inconsistency between the versions in your testing but I'd be surprised if you did.